# For loop in multiples of 2 delphi

Tags: loops, for-loop, delphi

new to Delphi, how would i get a for loop to increment in multiples of 2 instead of one ? So instead of:

```
procedure TForm1.button1click(Sender TObject);
var
i, x: integer;
begin
for i := 0 to 5 do;
x := IntToStr(i);
memo1.add.lines(x);
end;
```

so instead of output in memo box being being
0
1
2
3
4
5

it would be

0 2 4

Comment: (1) You mean `for i := 0 to 5 do begin x := IntToStr(i); Memo1.Lines.Add(x)`. (2) The answer to your question is `for i := 0 to 2 do begin x := IntToStr(2*i); Memo1.Lines.Add(x)`

Comment: The code presented does not output values from 0 to 5.

Comment: Btw, the reason your code as shown produces no output is that the `;` after `do` signals the end of your `for` loop.  So it `do`es nothing.

Comment: And even without the semicolon, you would only get a single line in the memo, "5", to be specific. (Can you see why?) With the semicolon, you also get a single line, but this time you get a "random" number (different each time).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, there are more errors, so this code does not compile for several reasons. 1) `x` is declared as integer instead of `String` 2) It should be `memo1.lines.add(x);` as you pointed out earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can of course just use a `while` loop.

```
i := 0;
while i < 6 do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i))
  Inc(i, 2);
end;
```

Comment: No, you don't have to use a `while` loop.

Comment: I personally find it easier in this situation to use a while loop myself. Post your answer we can see how your solution works.

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but I know how "my" solution "works"! And my point is that [have to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_to) means "must", so your statement is technically false.

Comment: I have corrected my post.

Comment: Thank you, now I won't complain any more! :)

Comment: I'd still like to see your solution though and so the OP has something to mark as the solution.

Comment: `while` loop is preferable here than convoluted `for` loop version. But `Inc` is the idiomatic way to increment a variable.

Comment: And of course `Memo1.Add.Lines(x)` must be `Memo1.Lines.Add(x)`.

Comment: Personally, I think that the `while` version is clearer because the intent is obvious whereas a missing `x2` multiplier in the `for` version may be a mistake or intentional.

Comment: I also agree that `while` loop is much better solution for such scenario. It is clean and easily understandable code not to mention easily expandable. For instance if you now decided that you want for your output to be in increments of N where N is any number you would only need to change `Inc(i,2)` to `Inc(i,N)`. Much cleaner than dividing maximum desired number with Increment and then multiplying current `for` loop cycle with the said Increment in each loop.

Comment: `FOR i := start TO end BY step DO`see [https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2016-february-stepping-values-for-loop.html](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2016-february-stepping-values-for-loop.html)